# Select project when clicking in a button within an ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am new in Android. Sorry if this is a silly question. 
I would like to obtain the project data contained in an ExpandableListView when the user clicks in the button. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSCDH.png)

Ex: When the user clicks in the Project 1 button, I want to obtain the data from Project 1.

Here is my HeaderView

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="0dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/project_title"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:paddingLeft="35dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@color/colorinnotholic"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="45sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:background="@color/colorinnotholic">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/select_project"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
        android:shadowColor="@null"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:onClick="selectProject"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now, you can see that in order to perform the action I included the onClick method within the XML file.

the selectProject method is

```
public void selectProject(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.select_project:
 //                final Project selectedProject = (Project) listAdapter.getChild(0,0);

        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

In the comment, you can see I am able to obtain the project manually. However, I am not able to obtained dynamically from the user action. My expandableListView.getSelectedItemPosition returns -1. I think this could probably be caused because I am directly accessing to the onclick method of the Button. However, I don't really know how to access in a different way. I have also tried using setOnChildClickListener, which provides the groupPosition and the childPosition.

Could anyone help, please?
If you think there is also a better way instead of including the button, I am open for that. Let me know if I should include code from my custom ExpandableListAdapter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all, 
I have finally found what I was looking for. I have created an interface as it was explained by @Rami in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27278290/add-clickable-imageview-in-expandablelistview). Hope it helps to other people.